# Log SOAP message sent from WCF proxy class client side on .NET 4.7.1

Tags: wcf, logging, soap, client, message

I have an WCF client app on .NET 4.7.1 and I'm hoping to capture full XML of the SOAP bodies sent to the WCF server which is out of our control.
I tried adding this to the app.config, but no messages were logged.

Could it be due to the fact that this WCF client app runs as a Windows service under the Local System account? I tried multiple output folder locations, and all of them had Local System enabled in their security permissions.

Does it require the exe to be a debug build?

```
<system.diagnostics>
      <sources>
         <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                      switchValue="All"
                      propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
               <add name="traceListener" />
            </listeners>
         </source>
         <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"
                      switchValue="All">
            <listeners>
               <add name="traceListener" />
            </listeners>
         </source>
      </sources>
      <sharedListeners>
         <add name="traceListener"
                 type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                 initializeData="c:\Traces.svclog" />
      </sharedListeners>
   </system.diagnostics>

   <system.serviceModel>
   <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true"
                                  logMalformedMessages="true"
                                  logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
                                  logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
                                  maxMessagesToLog="500"/>
   </diagnostics>



</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, switchValue can be set to the following values: Off, Critical, Error, Warning, Information, and Verbose. The Activity Tracing and Propagate Activity option enable you to use The WCF Activity Tracing feature. I think you can set the switchValue to Information, ActivityTracing. See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/recommended-settings-for-tracing-and-message-logging) for more details.

If this problem is not solved or new problems arise, you can also use the [Configuration Editor Tool (svcconfigEditor.exe)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/configuration-editor-tool-svcconfigeditor-exe).